# Value of type '[Users]' has no member 'username'

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a simple user login ViewController that connects to a database full of user information for my app but I get the error stated in the title.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class Users: Decodable {
    let username: String
    let email: String
    let password: String

    init(username: String, email: String, password: String) {
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
}


class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    var loggingin = [Users]()

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTxtField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTxtField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var checkCredsBtn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let jsonURL = "http://host-2:8888/getLogin.php"
        let url = URL(string: jsonURL)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            do {

                self.loggingin = try JSONDecoder().decode([Users].self, from: data!)

                for eachUser in self.loggingin {
                    print(eachUser.username + " : " + eachUser.password)
                }

            }
            catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()

    }
    @IBAction func checkCreds(_ sender: Any) {
        if usernameTxtField == loggingin.username && passwordTxtField == loggingin.password {
            print("YES")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `loggingin` is a `[User]` (a.k.a. `Array<User>`). The array contians `User` instances which have those properties, but the array itself doesn't have username or password fields.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of this compile time error appears in `checkCreds` function, you are trying to access the `username` and `password` properties directly from the array which is obviously incorrect. What you should do instead is to get the desired object from `loggingin` array and do comparing with its properties:

```
@IBAction func checkCreds(_ sender: Any) {
    let currentUser = loggingin[0]

    if usernameTxtField == currentUser.username && passwordTxtField == currentUser.password {
        print("YES")
    }
}
```

In the above example, I just got the first object; I would assume that you already able to get the desired object `currentUser` (what's the used index) for getting the object from the `loggingin`.